# How do I change the screen resolution after installing NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, display-resolution

I have another laptop that has graphics problems.  Its a Lenovo ThinkPad P50 running Ubuntu 16.04.  Its using an NVIDIA Quadro M2000 graphics card, and also has a 4K screen.  It didn't have the proper drivers, so I installed `nvidia-375` `nvidia-375-dev` `nvidia-modprobe` `nvidia-opencl-icd-375` `nvidia-prime` and `nvidia-settings`.

After installing the drivers, the resolution switched to 3840x2160 (16:9) making everything on the screen very small.  I go into the display settings and try to change the resolution, but 3840x2160 (16:9) is the only option.

After that didn't work, I tried `xrandr -s 1920x1080`, but that only made it so that I could just see a portion of the screen.

My last attempt was opening the **NVIDIA X Server Settings** and changing the resolution from there.  *NVIDIA X Server Settings > X Server display Configuration > Resolution*.  That did change the resolution, but it had the same result as `xrandr -s 1920x1080`.

For now I've had to go into the **System Settings** and change *Scale for menu and title bars* to 2.

Here is the output of `xrandr` without arguments.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
3840x2160     60.00*+
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us: What is too small? Maybe we can help you make those particular things big enough. -- I use a proprietary nvidia driver in one computer, and it is possible to *change* the resolution via the nvidia tool (like you describe). Is there only one available resolution? And what about `xrandr`? Are there more than one available resolutions?

Comment: @sudodus the entire screen is too small.  It thinks I'm using a huge screen when it's actually just 4K.  When I go into the settings I only see one available resolution.  I tried `xrandr` because I found on a different webpage somebody said you could change the resolution from there.

Comment: What is the physical size (in mm  or inches) of the monitor screen? I think 1920x1080 should work unless the screen is really small. What is the output of `xrandr`(without parameters)? Is there a list or only resolution available? What monitor is it (type, brand name, model)? Which nvidia driver are you using (number)? - With this information someone might recognize the cause of your problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove the nvidia driver and use the built-in (nouveau) graphics driver?

Comment: @sudodus hey sorry it took so long to respond.  I don't know what type of monitor it is.  It came with the laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad P50).  I am using the 375 nvidia drivers.  I'm not sure how large the screen is.  I added the output of `xrandr` to the original question.  I was using nouveau before and it was all fuzzy.

Comment: @Ruslan as stated in the original question, I already tried the nvidia settings.

Comment: Try using `xrandr`'s `--fb` and `--panning` options to make virtual desktop size equal to physical.

Comment: Try 1. Another version of nvidia proprietary driver; 2. The newest possible Ubuntu with the new possible linux kernel and hardware drivers - so a new nouveau driver. See this link to the QA testing tracker, http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/382/builds